# HTML5 Application Manifest Mobile Support

Tags: caching, html, mobile, manifest

Does anyone know of a grid/resource on the latest device support for HTML5 Application Manifest on mobile phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps

It's got a wealth of information on it, and is frequently updated.

Seems to be avaliable on all decent phones – it's on iOS, Android and Opera Mobile, but not Opera Mini (unsurprisingly).